# Weird Error - Undefined reference while linking to own library gcc

Tags: gcc, g++, linker-errors

I have little experience in creating and linking libraries but this time I am going crazy over this silly thing.

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ -m32 src/main.cpp -Iinc -lblpapi3_32 -I/tmp/diff/include -L/tmp/diff/lib -lbbbmds
/tmp/ccQCKwnF.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `MDS::BloombergSource::BloombergSource()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4ed): undefined reference to `MDS::BloombergSource::startSession()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `MDS::BloombergSource::openService()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `MDS::BloombergSource::authorize()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5fc): undefined reference to `MDS::BloombergSource::AddSubscription(char const*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, BloombergLP::blpapi::CorrelationId const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x655): undefined reference to `MDS::BloombergSource::subscribe()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Confirmed that my lib has reference to these functions, below for example

```
-bash-3.2$ nm /tmp/diff/lib/libbbbmds.so |grep startSession
0000000000002a62 t _ZN3MDS15BloombergSource12startSessionEv
```

Further confirmation,

```
-bash-3.2$ c++filt _ZN3MDS15BloombergSource12startSessionEv
MDS::BloombergSource::startSession()
```

Also,

```
-bash-3.2$ file /tmp/diff/lib/libbbbmds.so
/tmp/diff/lib/libbbbmds.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Have tried reordering the libs/src.

Comment: Show command lines used to build `libbbbmds.so`.

Answer (score 0):

`nm` output lists `MDS::BloombergSource::startSession()` function as `t` - a function with internal linkage. Such functions are not available from other translation units.